# Conjunctions and conditional clauses

Tags: conditional-constructions, conjunctions

> Your dental habits are awful, **but** if you brush and floss every day, you probably won’t get cavities or gum disease.

The conjunction is 'technically' joining a conditional clause followed by a independent clause. "But" is being used as a contrast. Can the other conjunctions be used in this way with the conditional clauses? Any rules etc.

Comment: No, it's not "a conditional clause followed by an independent clause'. They're both dependent -- this is an _if ... then ..._ construction -- and they are both covered by the _but_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Would you contend that in an "if... then..." construction, both clauses are subordinate (or do you define dependent clauses differently than subordinate ones - in which case is your contention that the "then..." clause isn't subordinate but is dependent)?  "You probably won't get cavities or gum disease" strikes me as a main clause.  Is it the implicit "then" that implies otherwise, from your point of view?

Comment: I would say that both clauses are subordinate (or dependent -- same meaning), because they're part of the _if ... then_ construction, making only a conditional assertion.

Answer (score 2):

the conjuction "but" joins the first clause to an "if...then.." structure. Both parts of the "if...then..." are covered by the "but".

There is a clear contrast between "Your dental habits are awful", and the conclusion "you won't get cavities".

Other conjunctions can be used similarly:

> You like beer, and if you visit Oktoberfest, you can drink a lot of it.
>
> You want to get fit, so if you can afford it, you should hire a personal trainer.

Comment: This is a good answer. I have no memory of it at all.